# LSPCI find multiple vga but not xrandr

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, multi-monitor, intel

I'm trying to run Debian Stretch, I tried installing Nvidia driver (the non-free one) and Intel driver, I tried to setup manually my Xorg.conf, but nothing changed. Even tried with nouveau, but nothing. It won't work.
My motherboard see the connected PCI, they have their vga connected to a working scree (tested earlier)

```
giampli@test:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
```

But xrandr can't see the second VGA, it see only one screen.

```
giampli@test:~$ sudo xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

I can't really understand why.
Excuse for my bad English, I'm not mother tongue.

Comment: Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for errors (or any output) regarding the Nvidia driver. Maybe your configuration isn't being read at all.

Comment: @FerencWágner
Now i think everything it's loaded: 
`[     4.513] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"`
I also uploaded the complete log here https://pastebin.com/mqc1h9j9
I'm actually using nouveau and modesetting, they where the default driver installed

Answer (score 0):

According to the linked Xorg.log (please edit your question, don't add new information in comments) the modesetting driver recognizes the Intel card and the attached screen via HDMI/DVI, but Nouveau doesn't seem to detect your NVIDIA graphics card.

Nouveau [does support](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=linux-4.1-gtx-750-nouveau) the GTX 750 Ti since 2015. Make sure both your kernel and the nouveau driver are the newest version.